# Joining Entity with Inner and Left Outer Join

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dto

I have 2 entities  and one DTO

```
Entity
@Table(name = "A")
class A
{

private String idA;

private String businessLine;

private String name1;

private String name2;

private String name3;

private String name4;


private String date;

private String city;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
class B
{

private String idb;

private String businessLine;

private String name1;

private String name2;

private String name3;

private String name4;


private String street;

private String zip;
}
```

There is no staright way to join entity A to B.

If businessLine='USA' then join entity A with entity B on  businessLine and name1 to get a single object(row)  (Left outer join i.e all rows of A)

If businessLine='JPN' then join entity A with entity B on  businessLine and name2 to get a single object(row)  (Left outer join i.e all rows of A)

If businessLine='GER' then join entity A with entity B on  businessLine and name3 to get a single object(row)  (Left outer join i.e all rows of A)

If businessLine='IND' then get data from Entity A only

If businessLine='CHN' then get data from Entity B only

```
List<A> a = aDataRepository.findByBusinessLine(businessLine);
List<B> b =bDataRepository.findByBusinessLine(businessLine);
```

**How can i form one object of  A and Entity B depending on busilessLine i pass and set it to DTO**

Comment: Perhaps you can create a discriminator for that then you can use inheritance on entities

Comment: what do you mean by "discriminator " ?

Comment: discriminator'd be your businessLine...  did you fix it? or you still want an answer

Comment: no i have not fixed it.As i am not aware of how discriminator  works.Can you give the pseudo code.

Currently i am setting the value in Common DTO by fetching all the data in the list and iteraing over it by IF-ELSE condition.